# Rename multiple files without overwriting one with another in php

Tags: php, directory, overriding, rename, filenames

I have many files in a folder. And I want to rename them without overwriting one with another.

Let's say these are my file names:

- Ana.php
- Maria.php
- Ioana.php
- Georgiana.php
- Bianca.php

And I got an array telling me what files to rename:

```
array(
    "Maria.php"  => "Ioana.php",
    "Bianca.php" => "Cristina.php",
    "Ioana.php"  => "Daniela.php"
)
```

These is an example where `Ioana.php` got overwritten. Because `Maria.php` "wanted" that name.

Or let's say this example:

```
array(
    "Maria.php"  => "Ioana.php",
    "Ioana.php"  => "Maria.php"
)
```

These is an example where the files want to switch their name.

I need a solution where, no matter what files should be renamed, they never overwrite another file from the folder. Number of files, which should be renamed, could be different every time.

I need all array files to be renamed. The problem is how to do that without overwriting.

The name of the files are very important. Adding a timestamp suffix is not a good solution.

Comment: Have you tried anything for yourself so far?

Comment: I know only about rename() function. But I don't know what solution to use for what I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've created my own renaming multiple folder file names.

This function prevent overwiting as I explained and asked in the question (just at the top).

```
function rename (array $names): void {
    $dirname = '...';
    $files = File::folder($dirname); // 'File' is my own static class.

    foreach ($names as $key => $name) {
        $names[$key] = (basename($name) .'.'. File::extension($key));
        // 'File' is my own static class.
    }

    $duplicates = array(); // for avoiding overwriting
    foreach ($files as $key => $file) {
        $duplicates[$key] = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), '');
        copy($file, $duplicates[$key]);
    }

    foreach ($names as $key => $name) {
        if (isset($files[$key])) { // for preventing non-existent input filename
            // remove file if its name isn't used for renaming
            if (is_file($files[$key]) && !in_array($key, $names)) {
                unlink($files[$key]);
            }
            rename($duplicates[$key], $dirname .'/'. $names[$key]);
        }
    }
}

rename(array(
    "Maria.php"  => "Ioana",
    "Bianca.php" => "Cristina",
    "Ioana.php"  => "Daniela"
)); // Your new names don't have their extension, because you can't change the extension.
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `file_exists($filename)` to check before your rename you file if he exist like :

```
<?php
while(count($arr) > 0)
{
  foreach ($arr as &$value) {
    if (file_exists($value)) {
      rename($value,$value + "temp");

    }
    rename(array_search($value,$arr),$value);
    unset($tab[array_search($value, $arr)]);
  }
}
?>
```

You just have to loop on your  array until all the files as been rename

Comment: Thx for reply. I need all array files to be renamed. The problem is how to do that without overwriting.

Comment: I edited my code, it will not overwritting your file cause it check if the new name is already taken or not, you just have to add a condition to check if all the file have been replace

Comment: What contains $arr and what contains $array ? How it helps using address (&) of $value ?

Comment: $arr is your "replace name" array and $value the variable who will take each value and key of your array.

Comment: Thanks Jonathan. I added a new example for making the question more clearly.

Comment: I edit my answer, This script will do all the array without erase any file, for your exemple, you just have to edit my script to rename the file with a prefix, to free the name, and dont forget to update your array with the new name (prefix + current name of the file)

Comment: Thx for helping me. I don't understand what prefix you are talking about.

Comment: I edited my code, now the cript add an suffixe if the file exist, you just have to update your array name

Comment: Thanks for your time. The name of the files are very important. Adding a suffix is not a good solution.

Comment: Sure, but you just have to rename it if you need or pass the rename to prevent the overwriting, but it's at you to choose whant you want to do and code it, if it help you, dont forget to valid the answer